# Delegates, Lambdas, Action, Func, Anonymous Functions

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, anonymous-function

I just want to verify my understanding about the following

- **Delegate** - a method signature
- **Lambdas** - anonymous function
- **Anonymous Function** - just that
- **Action** - An anonymous function that returns nothing
- **Func** - An anonymous function that returns something

hmm... they all do similar things, how do you define & know when to use each?

*sorry, I don't explain well*

Comment: This is so broad that any attempt to answer this will just spawn an array of more questions. Read up the basics, and rather ask a question when you actually face a problem or have a question regarding a specific use of this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- **Delegate** - it is not a method signature. `It is a type which encapsulates a method`. Hence a delegate declaration should have a signature similar to the method it wants to encapsulate. `When to use Delegate - whenever you want to pass a method to another function.` For more see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173173%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).
- **Lambdas** - short hand and more expressive way of writing an anonymous function. But there is more to it. A lambda expression can also be converted to an expression tree. For more see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/lambdaexpressions.aspx).
- **Anonymous Function** - yes .. just that
- **Action** - It is a delegate which can encapsulate a function that returns nothing. So you should think of it as `a type that can encapsulate an action` and use it when you need to pass an action around.
- **Func** - A delegate that can encapsulate a function that returns something. But you should look at it as `a type that can encapsulate a transformation` and use when you want to pass around a transformation.

Comment: I am wondering then, why can't I pass a delegate instead of a `Action` or `Func`.

Comment: Action and Func are delegates which are provided by .Net. So you when you create an instance of Action like Action myAction = myMethod; and pass it you are actually passing a delegate around.

Answer (score 4):

[Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) and [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) are just special cases of the [Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx). Delegate itself is something that references a method and can be used to call it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to see C# + these features. Also because there is not a strict pragmatic answer to your question.

Start from a functional programming point of view, for example try to learn F# to get inside what and when lambdas are used (actually everywhere inside a functional language) and then you'll understand things better.

It will open your mind and make you think differently about imperative programming or mixed languages like C#.

Comment: I looked at some F# videos, very interesting esp. [the one by Luca Bolognese](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/pdc2008/tl11) @PDC08. But I don't really get much, then I stopped watching those, maybe I should start looking @ them again