# I'm confused about optional anonymous functions in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, action, anonymous-function

I code a lot of languages: `Java`, `PHP`, `C#`, `JQuery` to name but a few, but  I am only *fair to middling* in C# and I am confused as to how to use Anonymous functions. I have seen numerous references to `Action<T>`, `lambda` and `delegates` but I am not sure what they are and how they matter:

I am (however) pretty used to JQuery which does it like this:

```
function hello(fnc){
     console.log("Hello");
     if (typeof fnc === "function") fnc();
}
hello();                                       //prints "Hello"
hello(function () {console.log("World"); });   //prints "Hello\nWorld"
```

Now, I use this as an example: how can I do this is `C#` also I am curious as to what happens to the `classes` EG:

```
class foo
{
    public void action()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Hello");
    }

    public void action(Delegate fnc)
    {
        action();
        control.Invoke((MethodInvoker)fnc);
    }

}
foo FOO = new foo();
FOO.action();                         //prints "Hello"
FOO.action(() => {                    //prints "Hello\nWorld"
   Debug.WriteLine("World"); 
});
```

so my questions are a) does this work / am I close (I can't check I am not at work PC atm) and b) how about passing a parameter (i.e. a scope question):

```
foo FOO = new foo();
string yay = "Yeah";
FOO.action(() => {                    //prints "Hello\nWorldYeah"
   Debug.WriteLine("World" + yay); 
});
```

EDIT

[image: a screen shot of it erroring]

Comment: @eddie_cat not sure what you mean? are you asking why I wrote heavily comprehensive pseudo code the question? If so, I put in the care and attention because I want to know how to form it. Nice answer tho

Comment: I think you've come to the wrong web site eddie thanks for your answers, they are appreciated but I want this question to get some real responses, have you had a bad day? I have bothered to try it I spent some hours trying it any which way.. some how this is showing a lack of reseach in your eyes?

Comment: Not at all. I'm just telling you why I gave you a -1. Which is what you asked.

Comment: you gave me a -1 because you think I haven't shown enough real research? Is that really fair? I (personally) think this question is actually *well* formed (based on the poor examples online if I google things)

Comment: Sure, it's well-formed. But it's not a good question for SO. You actually *state* that you haven't tried to experiment with this yourself before asking here. And there are plenty of tutorials available on this subject. I'm not saying you can't ask a question about something if you run into problems; I'm saying that it seems you haven't had the chance to run into problems yet.

Comment: -1 here too. I didn't understand lambdas at one point so I know from first hand experience there's tons of good tutorials/SO answers/etc.. on the subject. Also, I completely agree with @eddie_cat. Wait until you can get to a computer to test it out before asking.

Comment: I logged onto a remote session and ran it, I have to say, me providing detailed `pseudocode` is some rather odd way of being chastized, but I can see you're obviously rather upset over it.

Comment: @eddie_cat please help show where I stated that I haven't tried it? I said I can't check it at the moment, there is a lot of difference, one simply doesn't preclude the other at all. I think perhaps you have assumed too much and got angry over the wrong thing  ~Smith.h.Neil I disagree that there are good examples, there are *examples* but all of them are not clear enough to me (based on 30 or 40 looks including SO)

Comment: I'm not angry. My issue with your original post is that you asked `a) does this work / am I close`. You should *know* if the code you're posting on SO works. You should have tried to make it work, and you should be able to explain what you tried that didn't work. That's the issue I had with your post.

Comment: ok, so you 've agreed that I actually didn't say I haven't tried it and you're angry simply of the pseudocode. Now, there is a lot of ascii here I am looking at, but none of it answering a legitimate question I actually still have. This chatter has only  derailed me getting help and so I am not sure you meant to do that but that's what has happened.

Comment: "but I am not sure what they are and how they matter" - [Literally the first related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275269/delegates-lambdas-action-func-anonymous-functions?rq=1). That should get you started.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil it has no code, sorry to stick to my guns on this but you're both really quite wrong to berate this question so much

Comment: I said it'll get you started. Not give you the exact code you need.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil I had already read it

Comment: No one is berating you. And I already said I'm not angry. I said you hadn't tried to *test* it, which you proved when you asked if it works as your first question. You should know if it works. You would know if you had tried. And I shall not reiterate my point again, because you're not listening to me. Good luck to you.

Comment: I actually don't have a problem with the question, but I don't understand what you are asking. Yes, you basically have the right idea (no clue what that `control.Invoke` thing is about though). I would have used an `Action` as my parameter instead of `Delegate`. Your "scope" question looks fine. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: You should include the text of error messages generated in your code in the question, not just take a picture of the editor displaying the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

despite the lack of help from the SO self appointed police  (who remain wrong, and who would rather punish questions needing answers rather than give answers) I fixed it myself with **no help from them**.. so for posterity here is how to do it

```
class foo
{
    public void action()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Hello");
    }

    public void action(Action fnc)
    {
        action();
        fnc();
    }
}
```

and to call it

```
foo FOO = new foo();
FOO.action();                         //prints "Hello"
FOO.action((Action)(() =>
{                                     //prints "Hello\nWorld"
    Debug.WriteLine("World");
}));

string yay = "Yeah";
FOO.action((Action)(() =>
{                    //prints "Hello\nWorldYeah" - this will indeed still print "Yeah"
    Debug.WriteLine("World" + yay);
}));
```

using this technique you can send anonymous callback functions to c# methods

Comment: if you'd posted an answer you might have had a time and place to say that

Comment: I can also say that in a comment without needing to post an answer, because it's not the answer to the question, it's just you adding unnecessary code from the code in the question to your answer for no productive reason.  In fact, since it's not even a problem with the question *it wouldn't belong in an answer*.  Since it's a problem solely with your answer, it belongs as a comment to your answer.