# Extension Method Returning <T> Instead of Result<T>

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, func

I'm studying Vladimir Khorikov's `Result` class and how it can be used to chain Result operations.

Their original article can be found [here](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/functional-c-handling-failures-input-errors/).

Their original `Result` class code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/vkhorikov/7852c7606f27c52bc288).

My edited `Result` class codes are as follows:

```
public class Result
{
    private bool _isSuccess;
    private string _errorMsg = "";

    public bool IsSuccess()
    {
        return _isSuccess;
    }

    public bool IsFailure()
    {
        return !_isSuccess;
    }

    public string ErrorMsg()
    {
        return _errorMsg;
    }

    public Result(bool isSuccess, string errorMsg)
    {
        bool errorMsgIsEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMsg);

        if (isSuccess && !errorMsgIsEmpty)
        {
            throw new Exception("cannot have error message for successful result");
        }
        else if (!isSuccess && errorMsgIsEmpty)
        {
            throw new Exception("must have error message for unsuccessful result");
        }

        _isSuccess = isSuccess;

        if (!errorMsgIsEmpty)
        {
            _errorMsg = errorMsg;
        }
    }

    public static Result Fail(string errorMsg)
    {
        return new Result(false, errorMsg);
    }

    public static Result<T> Fail<T>(string errorMsg)
    {
        return new Result<T>(default(T), false, errorMsg);
    }

    public static Result OK()
    {
        return new Result(true, "");
    }

    public static Result<T> OK<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Result<T>(value, true, "");
    }

    public static Result Combine(params Result[] results)
    {
        foreach (Result result in results)
        {
            if (result.IsFailure())
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return OK();
    }
}

public class Result<T> : Result
{
    private T _value;

    public T Value()
    {
        return _value;
    }

    public Result(T value, bool isSuccess, string errorMsg) : base(isSuccess, errorMsg)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

I am working with the following test class:

```
public class Fruit
{
    private string _name = "";
    private StringBuilder _attribs;
    public bool isBad;

    public Fruit(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
        _attribs = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public string Name()
    {
        return _name;
    }

    public string Attribs()
    {
        string attribs = _attribs.ToString();

        if (attribs.Length > 0)
        {
            return attribs.Remove(attribs.Length - 2);
        }

        return attribs;
    }

    public void AddAttrib(string attrib)
    {
        _attribs.Append(attrib + ", ");
    }
}
```

Below is the class that operates on `Fruit`:

```
public class FruitOperator
{
    public static Result<Fruit> AddAttribToFruit(Fruit fruit, string attrib, bool fail)
    {
        if (fail)
        {
            return Result.Fail<Fruit>("failed");
        }

        fruit.AddAttrib(attrib);

        return Result.OK<Fruit>(fruit);
    }

    public static void MarkFruitAsBad(Fruit fruit)
    {
        fruit.isBad = true;
    }
}
```

I have created the following `Result` extension methods to match the function signatures of `AddAttribToFruit` and `MarkFruitAsBad`:

```
public static class ResultExtensions
{
    public static Result<T> OnSuccess<T>(this Result<T> result, Func<T, string, bool, Result<T>> func, T val, string str, bool flag)
    {
        if (result.IsFailure())
        {
            return result;
        }

        return func(val, str, flag);
    }

    public static Result<T> OnFailure<T>(this Result<T> result, Action<T> action)
    {
        if (result.IsFailure())
        {
            action(result.Value());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

My problem is when I try to use the result of `OnSuccess` in the next operation:

```
Fruit fruit = new Fruit("apple");
Result<Fruit> fruitResult = FruitOperator.AddAttribToFruit(fruit, "big", false)
.OnSuccess(FruitOperator.AddAttribToFruit, fruit, "red", true)
.OnFailure(lastFruitResult => FruitOperator.MarkFruitAsBad(lastFruitResult.Value()));
```

Above, `lastFruitResult` is actually a `Fruit` instead my expected `Result<Fruit>`.

Is there something wrong with my extension method signatures, or is there something that I need to change with how I'm using them?

Comment: Take a close look at `Action<T>` in `OnFailure<T>(this Result<T> result, Action<T> action)`

Comment: From the first look... change `Action<T> action` ->  `Action<Result<T>> action` in `OnFailure`

Comment: @smoksnes Hey, it actually worked! Could you add this as an answer so I can accept it? Also, could you add an explanation as to how changing `OnFailure`'s signature affects what I get from `OnSuccess`?

Comment: @Floating You don't get `lastFruitResult` from `OnSuccess`.

Comment: @John Oh? Where does it come from then?

Comment: `action(result.Value());`. [Try this code](https://rextester.com/YATAN59912) to understand it: `Action<string> DoWrite = (value) => Console.WriteLine(value); DoWrite("hello");`

Comment: @John So what `Action` needs dictates what I get from `identifier =>`? Could you link some documentation or article that explains why this happens?

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3282205/3181933) might help. If you've seen something like `list.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name == "TestUser");` then it's the same thing as you have here (except that's usually a `Predicate<ListItemType>` delegate).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206124/discussion-between-floating-sunfish-and-john).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your signature in `OnFailure` is slightly wrong. Change it to `OnFailure<T>(this Result<T> result, Action<Result<T>> action)`.

Basically an `Action` is a delegate that takes a number of parameters. The difference from `Func` is that `Action` doesn't return a value.

`OnFailure<T>(this Result<T> result, Action<T> action)` will let the consumer pass an action with the type `T` as input. In your case `T` is `Fruit` since it is actually defined in `AddAttribToFruit` because it returns `Result<Fruit>`.

By changing the signature to:
`OnFailure<T>(this Result<T> result, Action<Result<T>> action)` it will let the consumer create an action with the type `Result<T>`, which in your case is `Result<Fruit>`.

Your `OnFailure` should probably look something like this:

```
   public static Result<T> OnFailure<T>(this Result<T> result, Action<Result<T>> action)
   {
        if (result.IsFailure())
        {
            action(result); // Note that result is Result<T> and action takes Result<T> as parameter
        }

        return result;
    }
```

`lastFruitResult` will be the type definied within Action<*here*>.

Comment: Just wanted to add the final conclusion here. `Func` and `Action` determines the value (and data type) it gets from the object being extended when using `someIdentifer =>`.